# Missing link in "Please see: Why can't I post LMGTFY links?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message

I just tried to post a LMGTFY link in a comment (ok, ok, I realise it's rude, I shouldn't have tried it in the first place) and was greeted with a message informing me we're not allowed to do that (which stopped me doing a silly thing).

[image: lmgtfy not allowed]

The issue is, it says `Please see: Why can't I post LMGTFY links?` but there's no link in the red popup, and clicking it just makes the message disappear.

There's definitely no link:

[image: definitely no link]

Comment: There's a hint of irony in the fact that it's not directly linking to an answer, but rather, leaving the user to search for the answer themselves. Perhaps this should be [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: @Rob Haha I hadn't noticed the irony of it :P Not sure how this should be status-bydesign though, it's clearly intended to have a link.

Comment: Technically, there is no indication that it's supposed to be a link. But you would expect it to be a link for usability reasons. So maybe this of more of a feature request than a bug.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I would say it strongly implies it should be a link by saying `Please see:` and then using a very specific title. I could be wrong, of course; there's no _explicit_ evidence that it should be a link. But it's worded in such a way that I would be extremely surprised if the intention was for us to open a new tab, google it (because you can't even block-select, right-click and "Search google for...") and hope we (which could be a new, inexperienced user) find the correct link to click in the search results.

Comment: I agree that it is not good thing in User experience but it isn't a bug either unless it says `Please see the link`.

Comment: @Enzokie It's a bug if it isn't intended behaviour. Presumably someone who knows for sure will respond at some point so (IMHO) there's no point speculating until they do.

Comment: `sed 's/see/google/g'`

Comment: @Cœur It took me quite a while to work out what `sed` is and does, and what your proposed command would do. And in response, I laugh and say yes, that would indeed solve the issue, but it would be a hacky solution :P

Comment: "Please see" has a long history in dead tree paper formats; it doesn't imply you can click on anything.

Comment: @Kaz: so in printed edition of stackoverflow it would be fine. In hypertext edition information is expected to be, well, hyperlinked.

Comment: IMO, the section that suggests other questions that match your title should be more visible :)

Comment: @HansPassant, That now returns this question as the top result, thus demonstrating the uselessness of "let me google that for you" comments.

Comment: Actually, not a duplicate, but definitely worth actually linking in that question.

Comment: @ymbirtt the first result is not the only result. If you give up after clicking the first link, then I'd say there is a "lack of research effort" from your side. You should at least go through a bunch of stuff and read some articles before you expect strange people on the internet to spent more time for you, than you actually spent for yourself

Comment: @ymbirtt I feel like you didn't read the question :/

Comment: it seems that people in this discussion are talking about LMGTFY validity and not on what OP has noticed, that there is a missing link, i'm actually interested on what is on the other side

Comment: @AndersonPimentel You obviously didn't read the question. This is about the text of the error message not being hyperlinked to anything even though it implies that it is linked to something

Comment: But you can link to  LMDDGTFY! https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=Why%20can%27t%20I%20post%20LMGTFY%20links%3F

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, this appears to be one of those non-obvious behaviors that cause nothing but headaches: the internal logic adds a rel attribute to the link that then causes the sanitizer to strip the link out entirely.

Fortunately, there's an easy work-around, and since only like two people ever use this tool it should be easy enough to remember. I've fixed this one & will do a spot-check on other blacklist entries to ensure they work too.

[image: Screenshot courtesy of Steven Vascellaro]

Thanks for the report. Kudos to bluefeet for asking around about it internally and Adam Lear for diagnosing the root cause.

Comment: I question the validity of "easy enough to remember". My memory isn't as good as it used to be. Fortunately I tend to just cargo cult this sort of thing.

Comment: I mean... For *new* messages it's pretty easy to remember 'cause they obviously don't work. This one was hard to diagnose because it's been a lotta years since I added it.

Comment: Awesome, glad it was fixed properly!

Comment: I love that it's basically google query :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? http://imgur.com/a/GRMMR I get the HTML code of the link.

Comment: Yeah, it's all busted for editing comments, @GolezTrol. Works for posting them though. Might be worth another bug report.

Answer (score 33):

Instead of adding a link, I'd propose this small modification in the message text as a solution:

---

[image: Google that for yourself]

---

Comment: Why though? Why not just add a link? It seems like if you're there editing the box anyway, why not just add a link?

Comment: I mean I have nothing against googling, but it just seems like a workaround solution when it would be so incredibly easy to add a clickable hyperlink.

Comment: Why though? Why add a link? It seems like if you're posting links to LMGTFY anyway, you apparently like people to search, even if the link to the right solution was already at hand.

Comment: So it's to troll people that want to post LMGTFY links? That seems a bit childish and unproductive. Usually people try to post LMGTFY links when it's blatantly obvious that the person asking the question didn't even try to google the solution before posting. It's used to berate people for not searching first. I understand that person may have tried to search but not known the terminology, for instance, so the LMGTFY link would be insulting and rude. However it doesn't make sense to force the person trying to post the LMGTFY link to type the search into google.

Comment: Clonkex, aww come on. It's funny and actually useful, because that small text already explains pretty well what the problem is with links to Google or the general advice to google. If you think this is trolling already, you should grow thicker skin, or the internet will kill you. Links to LMGTFY are childish and unproductive in the same way (just a direct link to a google search would be faster for both parties *and* slightly less rude). My suggestion is to indicate that in a playful way. If you (or other LMGTFY'ers) are angry because of this, it only proves the point.

Comment: I'm not angry in the least, nor would I personally feel trolled by it (only inconvenienced that I have to remember and manually search the text if I want to know why we're not allowed to post LMGTFY links). But I do feel like SO is meant to be a professional and courteous place, and that the website itself should not set an example for trolling. Out of curiosity, did you photoshop the image to change the text, or just edit the HTML and take a screenshot? You'd be amazed how long it took me to realise I could create mockups just by editing the HTML of a page :P

Comment: @Clonkex people posting LMGTFY links are trolling by definition, why not troll them back?

Comment: @GolezTrol I'm curious as to why you wouldn't advocate for changing the link to something like `http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Why+can%27t+we+post+LMGTFY+links+in+comments%3F`

Comment: @TinyGiant Well if I had to answer that, it would be because it would seem pointless when it's not something the LMGTFY-poster could have been expected to google beforehand. That would be a genuinely bad idea IMO.

Comment: @Clonkex Yes, I changed the HTML and made a screenshot.

Comment: I think this change will add a nice sense of irony to the error message, but this change should be in addition to making the text a link, and not a substitute. The link can be to a google search for those words instead of the related SO page, and I'd be fine with that, but there still should be a link.

Comment: This solution is the easiest by far, because a change in plain text is gonna work, while adding HTML in there will need some thorough testing.

Comment: Brilliant idea. _durus iocus, sed iocus_

Comment: Poetic justice.

Comment: The difference is in the application that wishes to attract an expert to contribute their time, and the expert (protecting that time from another user who ALSO wants that expert's time) wishing to post a LMGTFY link. If StackOverflow wishes to tell the expert to get lost, as it often seems to... well surely they will. Personally, I definitely will not stop to Google why it wants me to get lost. The expert is the resource being courted. Why not provide him/her in-line assistance on how to use the system?

Comment: @TinyGiant lmgtfy is not trolling. it's a simple way of pointing to someone they are missing something essential. and almost always they resolve the situation (esp. as soon as they are being given at stackexchange)

Comment: @jungle_mole LMGTFY is rude, condescending, and blatant trolling. Plain and simple. There are no two ways about it. Let alone the fact that if the information is not easily found _on Stack Overflow_, then posting an LMGTFY link is counter productive and flat out wrong.

Comment: Try it *now...*

Comment: @Shog9 I appear to be able to post both versions; http and https.  Did something break?

Comment: Are you testing on meta, @dae? 'cause this ain't on meta.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks; wasn't aware of that bit.  I was.

Comment: @TinyGiant There's questions, you paste exact title text to google and you get the answer. Two situations: the question is trivial or author finally came up with the correct search term for google. In first case, saying lmgtfy is somewhat condescending, but is not trolling. In second case, well, here's your answer, you've found it yourself. In both cases, pointing to this fact is useful, because it's opportune situation to review.  this is all true, if "lmgtfy"-guy is correct ofc, otherwise he's ignorant show off, comment will be treated the same way any irrelevant/obscene comment is treated.