# Why is LMDDGTFY allowed while LMGTFY is not?

Tags: discussion, comments

After reading [this question on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350959/missing-link-in-please-see-why-cant-i-post-lmgtfy-links) I was wondering if there's a valid reason to not block [Let Me DuckDuckGo That For You](https://lmddgtfy.net/).

I know it's not nearly as famous, but I think the same reasoning about banning LMGTFY applies here, i.e. answering with these kind of links defeats the purpose of building a good knowledge base.

Comment: I think I'm going to get busy making a LMSOTFY.

Comment: @Ihazkode [Done](http://lmsotfy.com/)

Comment: There is a point at which suppressing speech gets just plain silly.  If you can't find an arbitrary URL to convey a snarky message then [you're just not trying very hard](http://68.media.tumblr.com/55079799d71618b3d3364b5c7a7d4b7f/tumblr_n07r066mbO1tohlexo1_1280.jpg).

Comment: What about LMBTFY?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there's only like 4 people that use Bing and chances are, they are not answering questions.

Comment: @Ihazkode I considered that a good joke for that reason.

Comment: The real question is... is LMSOTFY allowed?

Comment: @Lundin does closing as a duplicate count?

Comment: @BhargavRao Just found my new lets-annoy-my-coworkers toy for the month

Comment: @BhargavRao @Ihazkode `the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` for tinyUrl

Comment: you could potentially circumvent this situation by disallowing all urls matching a regex of `/lm[a-z]{1-4}tfy/`

Comment: I feel like LMSOTFY should still just be a google search...

Comment: @BhargavRao Well done, but [http://lmsotfy.com/?q=lmsotfy] doesn't find this page!

Comment: @TripeHound Should it though? This is meta and that's just searching the main site.

Comment: @Dason Can we have LMMSOTFY then?

Comment: @Ihazkode 'there's only like 4 people that use Bing' - how exactly do you know my wife?   :)

Comment: How about 'Let Me Debug That For You', 'LMDTFY'.  We could point it at gdb documentation.

Comment: To invetigate your question and the issues raised, I Googled your exact title and got 'About 308 results'.

Comment: @BhargavRao Your LMSOTFY should redirect the search either to the relevant of votes page, it now redirects to newest, and that is not the default of the search bar

Comment: [How to shatter the barriers of reality and let *"the things beyond"* start crawling in](http://lmsotfy.com/?q=how+to+parse+html)

Comment: I'm starting to see a market in reworded LMGTFY sites. "Permit Me To Query Google On Your Behalf, Sire" should be my first.

Comment: [Not Meta Enough](http://lmsotfy.com/?q=Why+LMDDGTFY+is+allowed+while+LMGTFY+is+not%3F)

Comment: @BhargavRao what about LMSOMTFY

Comment: StackOverflow has censoring????????? Bad.

Comment: Hooray, that was my question that led to asking this question ^_^

Comment: When will LMRTFSCFY be a thing?

Comment: I dunno, let me effing goog that effer for you - LMFGTFYYF!

Comment: +1 for showing me new "Let me do that for you" sites I didn't know before

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The reason behind blocking LMGTFY is two fold.  First, because it isn't constructive/polite, and second, because it is common.

LMDDGTFY and LMBTFY both pass the first criterion, but not the second.

Comment: Why does it matter how commonly used it is?

Comment: @DBedrenko Because one can not code all the possibilities that anyone can ever come up with. There are many other search engines less popular than DDG. If popularity doesn't matter every possibility with any kind of search engine/search option in the world has to be has to be blacklisted... Which seems unrealistic and unnecessary...?

Comment: In other words, it isn't a problem until it becomes a problem.

Comment: @Yakk It's OK, I understood it now rom TJ's comment. That it's of little benefit to spend effort on blocking the many similar sites. You got the big one and that's enough.

Comment: I don't think it's so much a matter of it not being commonly used, as that *the staff just don't even know LMDDGTFY exists*. How can you ever hope to blacklist something you're unaware of? Unless we get them to blacklist anything that matches a pattern, like LM*TFY or some such.

Comment: @BoltClock You have a problem, and you think "I know, I can solve it with regular expressions".  And now you have 2 problems, your original problem and the regular expression.

Comment: @krillgar in other words, a latent problem waiting to explode.

Comment: The way I see it, a potential problem has a possibility of becoming a real problem, so if you are made aware of a problem risk, why not just add a fix to prevent the problem to begin with. It's not like this fix should take that much developer time to implement.

Comment: @TotZam Implement.  And test.  And add regression tests for.  And QA.  And maintain.  All the while, encouraging people with equally "potential problems" to bring up new things to filter on.  Opposed by one simple rule: Don't put crap in your code base.  To the best of [my ability to search](https://google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+link:lmddgtfy.com+-lmgtfy+-chat), LMDDGTFY has been used **ZERO TIMES** on stack overflow.  I can provide a list of 1 million URLs that would be inappropriate to post in a SO comment.

Comment: @TotZam - We don't ask SE employees to add every new spam URL to the blacklist as they come in, only those that are persistent problems. For low-volume cases, flags handle that just fine. LMGTFY was only blacklisted after [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) [complaints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77377/ban-lmgtfy-links-across-the-stack-exchange-network), and even then there were arguments against the blacklist. Blacklisting a term is something of a last resort to stop ongoing problems.

Comment: @BoltClock Maybe we need LMETSEFY (Let me enumerate the search engines for you)? :-)

Comment: "Why isn't every rude sentence I have ever personally conceived of individually added to the comment filter?! Clearly this is a bug!"

Comment: @MarkAmery: Take thine snark sir and inject it into some dark passage of your body! Wait, how come that got through...