# Why does the error message for LMGTFY links point to Google?

Tags: discussion

I tried to add a LMGTFY link in a comment to see what happen (I know that's it's banned). There's an error message, with [a link to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+can%27t+I+post+LMGTFY+links):

[image: Comments cannot contain that content. Please see: Why can't I post LMGTFY links?]

I understand why LMGTFY are banned, but why link to a Google search instead of the relevant Meta question?

Comment: So you feel it would be more convenient if there's just a link to something which actually answers your question (of why you can't post it) instead of pointing you to a search result? That seems like a very effective error message then.

Comment: I want to up-vote that error message.

Comment: @Dukeling I'd say it would more efficient.

Comment: Oh, the irony..

Comment: At least the top search result points to stackexchange.

Comment: I _think_ [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350959/missing-link-in-please-see-why-cant-i-post-lmgtfy-links?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment484425_351092) was the origin of that. See the comment by shog9 below that which, IIRC, was confirmation of the  change. I'm fairly certain that before that the link posted to the actual question. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @TinyGiant Thank you for that link. I hadn't seen that question when I searched meta about LMGTFY. I was missing the reason (irony) and it's good to see the discussion around it.

Comment: *Can't....stop....laughing....* (at the link in the error message, not at you, baudsp).

Comment: Of course, it was be much better if the link in the message was http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Why+can%27t+I+post+LMGTFY+links

Comment: @Holger: Restraint is essential in any joke. Linking to Google is subtle enough to make it *really* good.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I once gave a LMGTFY link with a stupidly arcane search incantation. Google search had more syntax back then.

Comment: "I tried to add a LMGTFY link in a comment to see what happen (I know that's it's banned)" As a side issue, be mindful of where you're experimenting with these types of comments. Put them under one of your own posts. I typically choose one of my own answers to experiment with comments.

Comment: @Holger That's discussed at the conversation linked to by Tiny Giant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350959/missing-link-in-please-see-why-cant-i-post-lmgtfy-links?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment484425_351092

Comment: @YvetteColomb Thank you for the advice. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @JimBalter yes, I noticed after writing my comment

Comment: It would be awesome if it pointed to http://bfy.tw/ODIz

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the following comment inspired the link:

> @GolezTrol I'm curious as to why you wouldn't advocate for changing the link to something like `http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Why+can%27t+we+post+LMGTFY+links+in+comments%3F` – Tiny Giant Jun 21 '17 at 22:55
>
> <sup>- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350959#comment484425_351092</sup>

This would have been an LMGTFY search for *"Why can't we post LMGTFY links in comments?"*

Below that comment, Shog9 posted the following comment as what I believe is a confirmation:

> Try it now... – Shog9♦ Jun 22 '17 at 20:11
>
> <sup>- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350959#comment484754_351092</sup>

The resulting URL was to a Google search for *"Why can't I post LMGTFY links?"* instead of the LMGTFY query suggested, probably for the reason mentioned in the this comment that was posted to your question here:

> Restraint is essential in any joke. Linking to Google is subtle enough to make it really good. – Nathan Tuggy 2 hours ago
>
> <sup>- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375204#comment637756_375204</sup>

The newest reference to the error message that I've been able to find is [Why can't we post LMGTFY links in comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299281) which quotes the error message as:

> Comments cannot contain that content

The question [LMGTFY link can't be added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255397/4639281) (posted almost 14 months prior) included a screenshot of the error with only the text:

> Comments can't contain that content

[image]

However, in the origin thread that I've suggested above, Shog9 also says:

> ... This one was hard to diagnose because it's been a lotta years since I added it. – Shog9♦ Jun 22 '17 at 20:09
>
> <sup>- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350959#comment484753_351136</sup>

He doesn't say what the link was prior to the bug that caused the link to be excluded, but he does say that it was there for *"a lotta years"*. I can't find a post whose title was ever *"Why can't I post LMGTFY links?"*.

So it's still not clear when the original link was added, or what it linked to. It may have linked to the *"Why can't we post LMGTFY links in comments?"* question, or it may have linked to a Google search all along. I don't know for sure, but hopefully Shog9 will come along and either confirm or deny this at some point.

Comment: I love the Internet!

Comment: I hate the internet... wastes too much time